# Marketo REST API - Approve Custom Activity Type created using REST API - 611 System Error

Tags: rest, marketo

I have created a custom activity type in marketo using their [REST API](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/activities/#create_type) endpoint `/rest/v1/activities/external/type.json` While apporving it using [REST API](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/approveCustomActivityTypeUsingPOST), I am getting Sytem Error 611 as response.

While trying to approve it from Marketo UI, I am getting `Error for Munchkin`

But, when I create activity type using Marketo UI, I am successfully able to approve it using REST API Call as well as UI.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here!

Comment: Would it be possible to share the full URL you are POSTing to type.json? Additionally, have you attempted to use `/rest/v1/activities/external/type/{apiName}/approve.json` to approve the new activity type you're attempting to create?

Comment: Yes, I have been using the ```/rest/v1/activities/external/type/{apiName}/approve.json```  to approve the new activity, that is when  I am getting the error ```Error for munchkin```